# Callback Hell, Geolocations - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, callback, geolocation

I am in Callback Hell, and I don't really get how I will get out of it.
I've tried reading other topics that touch on the subject and I still don't grasp the concept.

I am working with the Google Maps API v3 and I am trying to return the users current position so I can keep passing it on to other methods.

I have managed to succeed by using the jQuery .done() out of context, it throws a warning but I manage to get my coordinate object.

If I call userPosition, how can I make that method wait for the findUser method before returning the variable userPosition?

Edit: Uploaded wrong code, and after edit, the indentation sucks. :)

```
userPosition: function(position)
            {
                 if (typeof position === 'undefined') 
                 {
                      //Call on findUser, when ready callback it self to set variables
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     //var userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                     //return userPosition;
                 }
            },

findUser: function()
                {
                    var self = this;
                    if (navigator.geolocation)
                    {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                            function(position) { // If successful
                                self.userPosition(position);
                            }, 
                            function(e) { // If something went wrong
                                var errors = {
                                    1: 'Permission denied',
                                    2: 'Position unavailable',
                                    3: 'Request timeout'
                                };
                                alert("Error: " + errors[e.code]);
                            },
                            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: this.timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
                        );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Set flag
                    }
                },
```

Comment: If position is undefined you try to access its `coords` property? `userPosition` returns local variable, but call to `userPosition` doesn't use the return value? Are you sure this code does what you think it does?

Comment: The userPosition method as it is posted above works if i call findUser. What I want to do is not to call findUser, but to call userPosition and if userPosition(position) is undefined then call method findUser and on callback set var userPosition and return it.

This way I could for example call another method, say, showUser that plots out a marker on the map based off of the coordinates.

Comment: I don't see how it could work. If `position` is undefined, then trying to access `position.coords` should throw a ReferenceError. Edit: and the code has changed ;)

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now, this more of how I want it to be. 
If I skip the whole if-typof then it works when I call findUser.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I've done it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/M4LEY/).

```
var thing = {

  findUser: function (callback) {
    var _this = this;

    // use the getPos method to get the geolocation
    this.getPos(function (position) {
        var lat, lng, userPos;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lng = position.coords.longitude;

        // add the new lat lng to the userPosition variable
        _this.userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        // invoke the callback
        callback();
    });
    return this;
  },

  getPos: function (callback) {
    var geo = navigator.geolocation;
    if (geo) {

        // get the geolocation and pass it back to findUser
        geo.getCurrentPosition(callback);
    }
    return this;
  }
}

// if userPosition doesn't exist then grab the geolocation
if (!thing.userPosition) {
  thing.findUser(function () {
    console.log(thing.userPosition);
  });
} else {
  console.log(thing.userPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isUserLocationSet = false;
userPosition: function(position){

                if(!isUserLocationSet)
                {
                    settimeout(userPosition, 200);
                    return;
                }
                if (typeof position === 'undefined') 
                {
                    var userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    return userPosition;
                }
                console.log(typeof position);
            },

findUser: function(){
            //set isUserLocationSet to true on completion in this method
            var self = this;
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function(position) { // If successful
                        self.userPosition(position);
                    }, 
                    function(e) { // If something went wrong
                        var errors = {
                            1: 'Permission denied',
                            2: 'Position unavailable',
                            3: 'Request timeout'
                        };
                        alert("Error: " + errors[e.code]);
                    },
                    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: this.timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                // Set flag
            }
        }
```

Here you would check on the flag repetitively using settimeout and will keep calling the function until that flag is set.

Comment: Yes that could work but I would rather depend on pure callbacks than setting setTimeout. Thank you anyways.